# Search form with php

Tags: php, mysql

I get the following form my database which contain for year 2011 week 1 to week 20 and for year 2012 currently week 1. I want my user to choose 2011 first and then call the week to choose for example so that they dont choose for example week 10 and year 2012( which are not yet available).Any help most welcome.

```
<form name="myform" action="http://www.website.com/displaybook.php" method="get">
    <select size="1" name="d"> 
    <?
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT (Week) FROM data ORDER BY Week ASC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {

     echo "<option value='". $row['Week']."'>Week - ". $row['Week']."</option>";

        }

    ?>  
    </select>

    <select size="1" name="y"> 
    <?
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT (Year) FROM data ORDER BY Year Desc");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {

     echo "<option value='". $row['Year']."'>Season - ". $row['Year']."</option>";

        }

    ?>  

    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Get data">
    </form>
```

Comment: You need to write some Javascript to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `year` select before the `day` select... It will ajust the GET string automaticaly... Then, you create a little javascript to enable the second select when the first is selected, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getWeek()
{
    if (document.getElementById('y').value != '')
    {
        document.getElementById('d').disabled = ''; // this will enable the select
    }
}
</script>
```

And in your HTML:

```
<form name="myform" action="http://www.website.com/displaybook.php" method="get">
<select size="1" name="y" onchange="getWeek()"> 
<?
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT (Year) FROM data ORDER BY Year Desc");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo "<option value='". $row['Year']."'>Season - ". $row['Year']."</option>";
}

?>  
</select>
<select size="1" name="d" id="d" disabled="disabled"> 
<?
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT (Week) FROM data ORDER BY Week ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo "<option value='". $row['Week']."'>Week - ". $row['Week']."</option>";
}
?>  
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Get data">
</form>
```

Something like this should work great!

Comment: hi, when choose 2011 or 2012 it does not call week

Comment: found that you forget to add id="y" on line 2.But still when i choose 2012 i do get week to choose week 20 for example which are not yet available

Comment: So you wat the user to select a week that exist and that is passed or current?